# How to make middleware for all the routes

Tags: laravel

I have split my routes.php file into 5 different files (admin.php routes, client.php routes and so on). Now what I want is basically in each file, I got 100 routes for example). What I need is to use middleware and apply it to all the routes that exist in my app.

Solution 1) USE ROUTE GROUP and pass middleware there. If I do that, I would need to put all my routes in route::group and I have to write route:group in 5 different files.

Is there any way to write this middleware somewhere in one place and automatically globally apply it to all routes?

Comment: It might be somewhat belated, but I wonder if you could reply or otherwise interact on the answer below? It came within a few minutes of asking, but replying appears to have slipped your mind. Replying/voting is not mandatory, but it is encouraged - it is how we encourage people to keep answering.

Answer (score 4):

You can put it inside your Kernel (**app/Http/Kernel.php**).

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware::class,
    ],
];
```

Note that there is also another property named `$middleware` which is for **every** single route of your application.

For more information about middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/middleware#middleware-groups